# AWS SQS crashed in Laravel/Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, lumen, lumen-5.4

I have setup lumen microservice v9.0 and installed the following dependecies

```
"php": "^8.0",
"aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.263",
"dusterio/laravel-aws-worker": "^0.1.36",
"illuminate/redis": "^9.52",
"laravel/lumen-framework": "^9.0",
"predis/predis": "^2.1",
"pusher/pusher-php-server": "^7.2"
```

When I dispatch job from one microservice to this microservice, SQS job received but when is job received its crash with following error

> ERROR: Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #3 [ 
> callable $isDownForMaintenance ]] in class Illuminate\Queue\Worker
> {"exception":"[object]
> (Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException(code:
> 0): Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #3 [ 
> callable $isDownForMaintenance ]] in class Illuminate\Queue\Worker
> at /var/app/current/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php:1118)

Even two days before this code was working fine but today after deployment its working stop and getting crashed. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue I have spent a lot of time to fix this issue but failed

bootstrap/app.php

```
$app->register(Dusterio\AwsWorker\Integrations\LumenServiceProvider::class);
```